# how to connect beanstalk app to rds database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Am trying to connect to RDS (AWS MySQL) from my Spring web app which is deployed on (AWS BeanStalk).
after checking the logs I get the below

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 20 more
java.lang.Exception: Query failed
```

Spring dataContext.xml

```
<bean id="mysqlDataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://mydb.rds.amazonaws.com:3306" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I have also added BeanStalk security group ID to RDS In-bound rules, and I can access the RDS from my local PC (added all IPs rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding EC2 intance security group to RDS inbound rules and adding RDS security group to EC2 instance configuration